# Splitting an audio signal. Different paths give different output, but shouldn't. I may not understand impedance

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I have this simple audio circuit. Guitar goes in. I buffer the signal. I split the signal into two. One goes directly out (OUT A), and one goes into a voltage controlled amplifier and out to another opamp (to buffer and invert the signal back).
I'm a rookie and I may not understand impedance very well. But the result is that OUT A is very loud. Just as loud as many guitar pedal buffers i own. But OUT B is much more quiet. I'd like B to be as loud as A, when the VCA is at zero attenuation. Everything after the split is taken from the [AS2164](https://electricdruid.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/AS2164-Quad-VCA.pdf) Datasheet. What may go wrong here? Shouldn't they be equally loud?
The Control Voltage is indeed between 3.3 and 0.01 V. I control it through an Arduino into a DAC.
[image]

EDIT: If I add a matching 30K resister to the direct output, then OUT A and B have equal outputs. But it's not at all as loud as the clean buffered signal.

[image]

Comment: Is U2 supposed to be an inverting or non-inverting amplifier?

Comment: Remove the attenuator parts to eliminate attenuation. Fix the feedback on opamp U2.

Comment: @RusselH  - Yes, U2 is supposed to be inverting as the AS2164 is inverting the signal as well. This way OUT B will end up in phase with OUT A.

Answer (score 1):

When you ground the control voltage you should see unity gain (suggest connecting it to 0V via a low resistance to start).

Make sure to ground unused inputs and outputs as described on the bottom of page 4 of the datasheet. These chips are pretty sensitive and power rails, decoupling, unused pins etc all need to be correct or you get odd effects. Check the datasheet carefully and do everything recommended, to the letter.

Also on breadboard be sure to keep wires reasonably short and so on. Check carefully for oscillation etc with a scope as well.

(This is basically the old SSM2120 chip, I know from experience they can be tricky to get working right, once they are set up correctly they work really well.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried grounding every other in/out on the AS2164, and set the VC in to groud. No output change on OUT B. I also messured the CV from the dac to swing between 0.0 and 3.3 V pretty prescisely.

Comment: OK. check everything with an analogue scope, look for oscillation etc. I did a lot of design with these chips, I remember that they are super sensitive to oscillation and if everything is not very well done, they tend to oscillate and not function correctly.

Comment: Will try that! 
I just added an edit to the description, regarding adding another 30k resister, making the outputs equal. Dont know if there's any thought around that. Thanks again.

Comment: The VCA Curve is fine and acts really well. No oscillation. Just a lower final output than expected. And i'm unsure if it has to do with the VCA chip or the impedance/resistance around it.

Comment: you could put a low value resistor in series in between the VCA and the output op amp, say 10R, and see if the output current is approximately what you expect.

Comment: also - is the frequency response at the output as expected?

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. Two things were wrong.

Firstly I found that the ground of the OUT B was connected somewhere on the breadboard where the ground was somehow messed up by things not in use. That helped quite a bit.

Then I noticed the U2 op amp was somehow distorting the signal. I put the signal B into another op amp right after the split, and all was good.